# Extracting text data from PDF files

Tags: pdf, r, parser-generator

Is it possible to parse text data from PDF files in R? There [does not appear to be a relevant package for such extraction](http://crantastic.org/search?q=parse+pdf), but has anyone attempted or seen this done in R?

In [Python there is PDFMiner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637781/converting-a-pdf-to-text-html-in-python-so-i-can-parse-it), but I would like to keep this analysis all in R if possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: although the question is only vaguely related, the answer points out some interesting problem with text extraction from PDF files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732178/extracting-text-from-pdf-with-poppler-c

Comment: Thanks Nico.  Fortunately, the particular PDF I am working with are very simple text files, so hopefully this will be less of an issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Linux systems have `pdftotext` which I had reasonable success with.  By default, it creates `foo.txt` from a give `foo.pdf`.

That said, the text mining packages may have converters. A [quick rseek.org search](http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753:boaz1reyxd4&newwindow=1&q=parse+pdf+file&sa=Search+functions,+lists,+and+more&cof=FORID:11&siteurl=rseek.org/) seems to concur with your crantastic search.

Comment: You were right to suggest the text mining packages.  The `tm` package has `readPDF`, which seems to do exactly what I need.

Comment: And here is `pdftotext` in an `R` workflow, for those unfamiliar with Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19926301/1036500

Comment: can we extract text data from PDF files into html format

Comment: .@DirkEddelbuettel - Is there a way to read specific page of the PDF rather than full PDF?

Comment: You could use a pdf command-line tool to extract a particular page first and then read that.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - Yes. I want to do everything with `R`. I am using `pdftools()` library, but haven't found quick way to read specific page using this package.

Answer (score 30):

This is a very old thread, but for future reference: the [pdftools](https://ropensci.org/blog/2016/03/01/pdftools-and-jeroen) R package extracts text from PDFs.

Comment: This package is really the easiest way to get text from PDFs using R at the moment.

Comment: yes this thread was before pdftools. same for me - pretty useful tool. makes it relatively easy to extract even tables out of pdf files.

Answer (score 9):

A colleague turned me on to this handy open-source tool: http://tabula.nerdpower.org/. Install, upload the PDF, and select the table in the PDF that requires data-ization. Not a direct solution in R, but certainly better than manual labor.

Comment: If you are on Windows then you may use this free utility especially designed for the tables extraction from PDF https://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html (Disclosure: I worked under this utility)

Answer (score 9):

A purely R solution could be:

```
library('tm')
file <- 'namefile.pdf'
Rpdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))
corpus <- VCorpus(URISource(file), 
      readerControl = list(reader = Rpdf))
corpus.array <- content(content(corpus)[[1]])
```

then you'll have pdf lines in an array.

Answer (score 6):

```
install.packages("pdftools")
library(pdftools)


download.file("http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/gamecenter/56901/DEN_Gamebook.pdf", 
              "56901.DEN.Gamebook", mode = "wb")

txt <- pdf_text("56901.DEN.Gamebook")
cat(txt[1])
```

Answer (score 5):

The [tabula](http://tabula.technology/) PDF table extractor app is based around a command line application based on a Java JAR package, [tabula-extractor](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-extractor).

The [R tabulizer package](https://github.com/leeper/tabulizer) provides an R wrapper that makes it easy to pass in the path to a PDF file and get data extracted from data tables out.

Tabula will have a good go at guessing where the tables are, but you can also tell it which part of a page to look at by specifying a target area of the page.

Data can be extracted from multiple pages, and a different area can be specified for each page, if required.

For an example use case, see: [When Documents Become Databases – Tabulizer R Wrapper for Tabula PDF Table Extractor](https://blog.ouseful.info/2016/05/02/when-documents-become-databases-tabulizer-r-wrapper-for-tabula-pdf-table-extractor/).

Answer (score 2):

I used an external utility to do the conversion and called it from R. All files had a leading table with the desired information

Set path to pdftotxt.exe and convert pdf to text

```
exeFile <- "C:/Projects/xpdfbin-win-3.04/bin64/pdftotext.exe"

for(i in 1:length(pdfFracList)){
    fileNumber <- str_sub(pdfFracList[i], start = 1, end = -5)
    pdfSource <- paste0(reportDir,"/", fileNumber, ".pdf")
    txtDestination <- paste0(reportDir,"/", fileNumber, ".txt")
    print(paste0("File number ", i, ", Processing file ", pdfSource))
    system(paste(exeFile, "-table" , pdfSource, txtDestination, sep = " "), wait = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Ghostscript (see https://www.ghostscript.com/) software and call it from **R** as follows :

```
system2("C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs10.02.0\\bin\\gswin64c.exe", args="-sDEVICE=txtwrite -sOutputFile=- -q -dDOPDFMARKS -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH C:\\Annotated.pdf")
```

There is a free version of Ghostscript.