# Reading data from PDF files into R

Tags: linux, r, pdf, scrape, pdf-scraping

Is that even possible!?!

I have a bunch of legacy reports that I need to import into a database.  However, they're all in pdf format.  Are there any `R` packages that can read pdf?  Or should I leave that to a command line tool?

The reports were made in excel and then pdfed, so they have regular structure, but many blank "cells".

Comment: Taking a glance at CRAN, there doesn't appear to be any library that does that.  You might be better off using another language that has such libraries (Perl and Python, for example, both have them), grabbing the data that you need, and then writing it to a file that can be read by R.

Comment: @JackManey Thanks, that's what I thought. There is `readPDF` in the `tm` package (text mining), but it isn't exactly user friendly and I think it uses the command line utility `pdftotext` under the hood anyway.

Comment: You have my sympathies.  Maybe some day we'll live in a world where all data is available as data!

Comment: @gsk3 (+1) I appreciate the condolences... I spend most of my days wishing that.  And since people are paying attention and I didn't look hard enough... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852354/extracting-text-data-from-pdf-files) confirms my suspicions.

Comment: There is also the 
[grImport](http://www.warwick.ac.uk/statsdept/user-2011/TalkSlides/Contributed/18Aug_1400_KaleidIIIb_2-Murrell.pdf)
package, which can read PDF files, 
but it is designed to extract vector graphics -- 
the text will also be there, but perhaps not in a very useable form.

Comment: I've never had success with `tm::readPDF`, but managed a work-around using `pdftotext` in my `R` workflow like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19926301/1036500

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just a warning to others who may be hoping to extract data: PDF is a container, not a format.  If the original document does not contain actual text, as opposed to bitmapped images of text or possibly even uglier things than I can imagine, nothing other than OCR can help you.

On top of that, in my sad experience there's no guarantee that apps which create PDF docs all behave the same, so the data in your table may or may not be read out in the desired order (as a result of the way the doc was built).   Be cautious.

Probably better to make a couple grad students transcribe the data for you.  They're cheap :-)

Comment: I wish!  Some of us don't have grad students to do our bidding.  And I'm too low on the totem pole to hire interns (read lackeys).  But good advice!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'll accept your answer!  Particularly the last line.

Comment: Humans are lousy. I know because I am one and I know lots of others. They excel at three things: solving novel problems; creativity (music, arts and literature); and interpersonal emotional support or persuasion. They can not be relied upon to transcribe.

Answer (score 31):

So... this gets me close even on a fairly complex table.

Download a sample pdf from [bmi pdf](https://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/educational/lose_wt/BMI/bmi_tbl.pdf)

```
library(tm)

pdf <- readPDF(PdftotextOptions = "-layout")

dat <- pdf(elem = list(uri='bmi_tbl.pdf'), language='en', id='id1')

dat <- gsub(' +', ',', dat)
out <- read.csv(textConnection(dat), header=FALSE)
```

Comment: I am running into problems which I do not know how to solve. The following line `dat <- pdf(elem = list(uri='C:/Users/Farrel/Downloads/bmi_tbl.pdf'), language='en', id='id1')` produces the following error `Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\Farrel\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpegXWQ3\pdfinfo57c9716105': No such file or directory`.

Comment: it does not seem to work for me. I want to extract some text from that. let me know how I can do it.

Comment: it shows an error unused argument(PdftotextOptions = "-layout") Calls

Answer (score 13):

The current package *du jour* for getting text out of PDFs is [`pdftools`](https://ropensci.org/blog/2016/03/01/pdftools-and-jeroen) (successor to Rpoppler, noted above), works great on Linux, Windows and OSX:

```
install.packages("pdftools")
library(pdftools)
download.file("http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2805.pdf", "1403.2805.pdf", mode = "wb")
txt <- pdf_text("1403.2805.pdf")

# first page text
cat(txt[1])

# second page text
cat(txt[2])
```

Comment: I like this package.

Comment: You may also find https://github.com/ropenscilabs/tabulizer useful for extracting data from tables in PDF files

Comment: @Ben  this worked first time for me; great answer.  btw:  the French phrase is "du jour" which translates to "of the day", not "de jour" meaning "of day".  Sorry to be pedantic  :-)

Comment: @hackR Merci beaucoup pour votre commentaire ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can also (now) use the new (2015-07) `Rpoppler` pacakge:

```
Rpoppler::PDF_text(file)
```

It includes 3 functions (4, really, but one just gets you a ptr to the PDF object):

- `PDF_fonts`   PDF font information
- `PDF_info`    PDF document information
- `PDF_text`    PDF text extraction

(posting as an answer to help new searchers find the package).

Answer (score 4):

per zx8754 ... the following works in Win7 with pdftotext.exe in the working directory:

```
library(tm)
uri = 'bmi_tbl.pdf'
pdf = readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))(elem = list(uri = uri),
                                                language = "en", id = "id1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another that can be used with Acrobat Pro :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
acrobat_App <- COMCreate("AcroExch.App")
acrobat_PDDoc <- COMCreate("AcroExch.PDDoc")
acrobat_AVDoc <- COMCreate("AcroExch.AVDoc")
acrobat_PageContent <- COMCreate("AcroExch.HiliteList")
objADOStream <- COMCreate("ADODB.Stream")
acrobat_AVDoc$open("C:\\my_PDF.pdf", 1)
av_Doc <- acrobat_App$GetActiveDoc()
pdf_doc <- av_Doc$GetPDDoc()
pdf_doc$GetNumPages()
page_Number <- pdf_doc$AcquirePage(1)
acrobat_PageContent$Add(0, 9000)
sel_Text <- page_Number$CreatePageHilite(acrobat_PageContent)
index <- 0 : (sel_Text$GetNumText() - 1)
vec_Char <- rep("", length(index))

for(i in index)
{
  print(i)
  vec_Char[i] <- sel_Text$GetText(i)
}
```