# In R , Reading a PDF document

Tags: r

I would like yo read mydata.pdf  in R... I use the following lines comands

```
>pdf <- readPDF(PdftotextOptions = "-layout")

>dat <- pdf(elem = list(uri='bmi_tbl.pdf'), language='en', id='id1')
```

The first error is the following

```
> pdf <- readPDF(PdftotextOptions = "-layout")
 Error in readPDF(PdftotextOptions = "-layout") : 
 unused argument (PdftotextOptions = "-layout")
```

I dont know what is the problem

Comment: the problem is that there's no argument in `readPDF` called `PdftotextOptions`, just like the error message says

Comment: Cual seria la mejor manera de importar un pdf entonces?

Comment: Here are examples of what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19926301/1036500  & http://stackoverflow.com/a/17981259/1036500 Like you I've never been able to get `readPDF` to work.