# Importing data from a PDF to HTML using R

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way to import data from a .pdf file into HTML format using R?

I tried with the following code:

```
library(tm)
filename = "file.pdf"
doc <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))(elem = list(uri = filename),language = "en",id = "id1")
head(doc)
```

**Output in HTML displays as**:

```
## $content
##  [1] "                                    sample data"                                     
##  [2] ""                                                                           
##  [3] "                                  records"                                    
##  [4] ""                                                                           
##  [5] "                               31 July 2017"                                
##  [6] ""                                                                           
##  [7] ""                                                                           
##  [8] "R Markdown setup            
##  [9] ""                                                                           
## [10] ""                                                                           
## [11] "R Markdown"                                                                 
## [12] ""                                                                           
## [13] "This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for" 
## [14] "authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R"    
## [15] "Markdown see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com."                                 
## [16] "When you click the Knit button a document will be generated that includes"  
## [17] "both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the"
## [18] "document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:"                         
## [19] "{r cars} summary(cars)"
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the pdf file available here : https://fie.org/competition/2022/152/results/pools/pdf?lang=en

With the following code, I have been able to convert the PDF file to a html file :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

path_PDF <- "C:\\pdf_with_table.pdf"
path_Html <- "C:\\temp.html"

wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_PDF),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc$SaveAs2(path_Html, FileFormat = 9) # saves to html
```

From my point of view, it would be more straightforward to extract the tables directly from the PDF or to convert the PDF to a word file and extract the tables from the word file.