# Is it possible to allow a user to run a specific code chunk from R Studio direct from a PDF after it's knitted?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a r markdown file, and was curious if it's possible to run code chunks direct from a pdf after it's been knitted ?

Comment: No. A PDF is a static file. It is however possible to read text from a PDF file, as per here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592600/how-to-read-pdf-file-in-r

Comment: You could provide a link to a Shiny app in the PDF that runs the code.